# Create new iframe and load content synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

The goal is to create an iframe dynamically and synchronously append a SVG element to its document body.

We are trying to get this to work in Firefox.

Our research suggests Firefox resets iframes with a new document after appending iframes to the HTML. This triggers a load event, and only after this event can you successfully append content. Any content appended prior to the load event gets discarded.

The workaround, which is not ideal, is to wait for the load event then append the SVG element to the iframe.

Is it possible to avoid asynchronous behavior? We want to append the SVG element synchronously after creating the iframe.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWXjgM

```js
var newElem = $(document.createElement("div"));
newElem.html("hi there");
var iframe = $(document.createElement("iframe"));
iframe.contents().find("body").append(newElem);
$("#box").append(iframe);
$("#box").append(newElem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Have you really tested this code in Chrome? It doesn't work there either.

Comment: OK updated the question to remove the reference to Chrome. Just want to see it working in Firefox. This was a simplified version of our code base, so just narrowed the question to remove ambiguity. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Where does the iframe point to? Is it on the same domain as the parent page? Is it on the same sub-domain?

Comment: same domain as the parent page. it's just a way to sandbox an element from the parent.

Answer (score 2):

**tl:dr** Regardless of what is done the asynchronous nature of the iframe being loaded doesn't *appear* to be avoidable, however there is a synchronous way to add content dynamically to the iframe via `srcdoc` which "overrides" the default iframe `src` attribute from being used.

It would also appear there *may* be a solution with using [createHTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) but I have yet to be successful.

## Solution with `srcdoc`

### Explanation

*assuming that your dynamic iframes does not load content via `src` attribute*

According to the [HTML iframe specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element)

> When an iframe element is inserted into a document that has a browsing context, the user agent must create a nested browsing context, and then process the iframe attributes for the "first time".

The thing to take note is "process the iframe attributes for the first time". There is **no mention** to whether or not this process is synchronous nor asynchronous and it comes down to each browser's implementation.

As it has been mentioned, Chrome and Firefox have understood this process as asynchronous, which does make sense as the goal of the iframe is to load content from its `src` attribute and to invoke the `onload` callback.

If no `src` attribute is available it'll set it to `"about:blank"`

It is worth mentioning that before the browser checks to see if there is a `src` attribute exists, it'll first check to see if `srcdoc` is available which according to [MDN iframe doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc):

> srcdoc
>
> Inline HTML to embed, overriding the src attribute. If a browser does not support the srcdoc attribute, it will fall back to the URL in the src attribute.

### Working Example

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

iframe.addEventListener("load", function(){
  console.log("loaded...");
});

iframe.srcdoc = `
  <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
`;

iframe.srcdoc += `
  <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
  </svg>
`

container.append(iframe);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

## Solution with Web Extensions

If you're developing a web extension you will have access the [mozbrowser api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API#Browser_API_concepts_and_usage) and thus [`stop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/stop)

> The stop() method of the HTMLIFrameElement interface is used to stop loading the content of the `<iframe>`.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! your tldr suggests there is no working solution, yet your answer contains a section called, "working example" and explains that `srcdoc` should work since no loading events are called which could overwrite the inline doc. could you kindly clarify please? thanks!

Comment: I've created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joGLqN) from the code in this answer. Two things I'm seeing: a) the `load` event *is* generated even when using `srcdoc`, b) the `iframe`'s document is not populated until `load` has been fired.

Comment: @Louis thanks for the comment fixed. Also fixed **tl;dir** but will add more details later. Hope it's better.

Comment: Hi @kemicofa could you clarify what you mean by fixed? This codepen of the working solution also suggests the iframe's doc isn't populated until the load event has fired: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/arROWP